# Maximal (minimal) value of $S=x_1^2x_2+x_2^2x_3+\cdots+x_{n-1}^2x_n+x_n^2x_1$ on condition that $x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2=1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities

since $x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2=1$ is sphere,a compact set,so $S$ has a maximal(minimal) value. But when I try to solve it using the Lagrangian multiplier method, I don't know how to solve these equations. Clearly $x_1=x_2=x_3=\cdots = x_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is an extremal point, but I don't know if it's the maximal(minimal) value.

I want to know how to solve the problem. Also, could this problem be solved by elementary methods, like some inequality  techniques?

Comment: The point $x_1=...=x_n$ is neither the maximal nor minimal (probably for all $n$). For even $n$, choose $x_{2k}=0$ will give $S=0$ and $x_1=1/2\sqrt 2, x_2=1/\sqrt 2$ may give the maximal.

Comment: @Hhan I do not understand your maximal example, and it seems possible to have $S$ negative

Comment: @Hhan  It's true the point $x1=...=xn$ is neither the maximal nor minimal, but I'm not sure if it's a local maxium or minimum.

Comment: Proving that the equal $x$'s are the extreme $x$'s reduces to proving the inequality $$(x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2)^3-n(x_1^2x_2+\cdots+x_n^2x_1)^2 \ge 0$$

Comment: [Bordered Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian)

Comment: MSE is a proper forum for such questions.

Comment: Is your question whether $x_1= \dots = x_n$ is a local maximum, local minimum, or neither, or is your question what the true global maximum and minimum are? For the second one, I will add that the symmetry $(x_1,\dots, x_n) \to (-x_1,\dots, -x_n)$ shows the set of values of $S$ is symmetric under negation and so the minimum is minus the maximum.

Answer (score 6):

For $n=3$ we need to find $$\max_{a^2+b^2+c^2=1}(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a).$$
Indeed, let $\{|a|,|b|,|c|\}=\{x,y,z\}$, where $x\geq y\geq z\geq0$.

Thus, by Rearrangement and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2b\leq|a|\cdot(|a||b|)+|b|\cdot(|b||c|)+|c|\cdot(|c||a|)\leq$$
$$\leq x\cdot xy+y\cdot xz+z\cdot yz=y(x^2+xz+z^2)\leq y\left(x^2+\frac{x^2+z^2}{2}+z^2\right)=$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}y(1-y^2)=\frac{3}{2\sqrt2}\sqrt{2y^2(1-y^2)^2}\leq\frac{3}{2\sqrt2}\sqrt{\left(\frac{2y^2+2-2y^2}{3}\right)^3}=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}.$$
The equality occurs for $a=b=c=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$, which says that we got a maximal value.

For $n=4$ we need to find $$\max_{\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2=1}\sum_{cyc}a^2b.$$
Indeed, by C-S and AM-GM we obtain:

$$\sum_{cyc}a^2b\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}a^2\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2}=\sqrt{(a^2+c^2)(b^2+d^2)}\leq\frac{1}{2}(a^2+c^2+b^2+d^2)=\frac{1}{2}.$$
The equality occurs for $a=b=c=d=\frac{1}{2},$ which says that we got a maximal value.

For $n\geq5$ we can use the Lagrange Multipliers method, but it does not give nice numbers.

For example, for $n=5$ the maximum occurs, when $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)||(0.79...,3.24...,3.78...,2.48...,1),$ which gives a value $0.45...$

The following inequality is also true.

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be real numbers such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$. Prove that:
> $$a^3b^2+b^3c^2+c^3a^2\leq\frac{1}{3\sqrt3}.$$

Comment: `Maximize[{x[1]^2*x[2] + x[2]^2*x[3] + x[3]^2*x[1],  x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 + x[3]^2 == 1}, {x[1], x[2], x[3]}]//Simplify` confirms it.

Answer (score 2):

Math experiment done with Matematica shows nothing simple and nice.
$n=3$

```
Maximize[{x[1]^2*x[2] + x[2]^2*x[3] + x[3]^2*x[1], 
x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 + x[3]^2 == 1}, {x[1], x[2], x[3]}]
```

$$\left\{\frac{\left(\frac{3152 \sqrt{3}}{53}-\frac{9403}{53 \sqrt{3}}\right)^2}{\sqrt{3}}+\left(\frac{164555}{1007 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{54516 \sqrt{3}}{1007}\right)^2 \left(\frac{3152 \sqrt{3}}{53}-\frac{9403}{53 \sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{164555}{1007 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{54516 \sqrt{3}}{1007}\right),\left\{x(1)\to \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},x(2)\to \frac{164555}{1007 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{54516 \sqrt{3}}{1007},x(3)\to \frac{3152 \sqrt{3}}{53}-\frac{9403}{53 \sqrt{3}}\right\}\right\} $$

$n=4$

```
Maximize[{x[1]^2*x[2] + x[2]^2*x[3] + x[3]^2*x[4] + x[4]^2*x[1], 
x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 + x[3]^2 + x[4]^2 == 1}, {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]}]
```

$$\left\{\frac{1}{2},\left\{x(1)\to \frac{1}{2},x(2)\to \frac{1}{2},x(3)\to \frac{1}{2},x(4)\to \frac{1}{2}\right\}\right\}  $$
$n=5$

```
Maximize[{x[1]^2*x[2] + x[2]^2*x[3] + x[3]^2*x[4] + x[4]^2*x[5] +   x[5]^2*x[1], 
x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 + x[3]^2 + x[4]^2 + x[5]^2 == 1}, {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]}]
```

produces the output of length 27003.

The same issue with the minime, e.g.

```
Minimize[{x[1]^2*x[2] + x[2]^2*x[3] + x[3]^2*x[1], 
x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 + x[3]^2 == 1}, {x[1], x[2], x[3]}]
```

$$\left\{-\frac{\left(\frac{9403}{53 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{3152 \sqrt{3}}{53}\right)^2}{\sqrt{3}}+\left(\frac{54516 \sqrt{3}}{1007}-\frac{164555}{1007 \sqrt{3}}\right)^2 \left(\frac{9403}{53 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{3152 \sqrt{3}}{53}\right)+\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{54516 \sqrt{3}}{1007}-\frac{164555}{1007 \sqrt{3}}\right),\left\{x(1)\to -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},x(2)\to \frac{54516 \sqrt{3}}{1007}-\frac{164555}{1007 \sqrt{3}},x(3)\to \frac{9403}{53 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{3152 \sqrt{3}}{53}\right\}\right\} $$

Comment: What is your maximum for $S$ when $n=5$?

Comment: @MattF. Thank you. No, it is not so. E.g. `Maximize[{x[1]^2*x[2] + x[2]^2*x[3] + x[3]^2*x[4] + x[4]^2*x[5] + 
    x[5]^2*x[1], 
   x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 + x[3]^2 + x[4]^2 + x[5]^2 == 1}, {x[1], x[2], 
   x[3], x[4], x[5]}] // Simplify` still produces a  long output and `NMaximize[{x[1]^2*x[2] + x[2]^2*x[3] + x[3]^2*x[4] + x[4]^2*x[5] + 
   x[5]^2*x[1], 
  x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 + x[3]^2 + x[4]^2 + x[5]^2 == 1}, {x[1], x[2], x[3],
   x[4], x[5]}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]` performs `{0.452532, {x[1] -> 0.661899, x[2] -> 0.434777, x[3] -> 0.174964, 
  x[4] -> 0.138598, x[5] -> 0.568363}}`.

Comment: That $0.452532$ for $n=5$ makes sense.  I think you can exceed $0.451$ for any $n$.

Comment: @Henry: For $n=10$ `NMaximize` command of Mathematica results in `{0.451389, {x[1] -> 0.677084, x[2] -> 0.422378, x[3] -> 0.134391, 
  x[4] -> 0.0133399, x[5] -> 0.000131404, x[6] -> 5.61579*10^-9, 
  x[7] -> -8.43825*10^-9, x[8] -> -7.99726*10^-9, x[9] -> -0.557805, 
  x[10] -> -0.183765}}`

Comment: For example for $n\ge 5$, you can have (not quite maximal) $x_1=0.592, x_2=0.677, x_3=0.418, x_4=0.128, x_5 \approx 0.00995$ and all the rest $0$ giving $S\approx 0.45137$

Comment: Your $n=10$ case looks strange: you should not have any negative values for maximal $S$ - just take the positive versions to increase $S$

Comment: @Henry: There was a typo in my code. In fact, it should be `{0.451389, {x[1] -> 0.000131406, x[2] -> 1.5108*10^-8, 
  x[3] -> -4.01598*10^-8, x[4] -> -1.91736*10^-8, 
  x[5] -> 7.39988*10^-10, x[6] -> 0.587294, x[7] -> 0.677083, 
  x[8] -> 0.42238, x[9] -> 0.134393, x[10] -> 0.0133402}}`. Small negative numbers due to round-off errrors. `NMaximize`  may find a loval minimum in higher dimensions. Other methods give `0.451389` too.

Comment: That revised $n=10$ is not far from my suggestion

Comment: this is just undersimplified: for example, for $n=3$ we have $x(2)\to \frac{164555}{1007 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{54516 \sqrt{3}}{1007}=\frac1{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: @FedorPetrov: MattF already reported that, but he deleted his comment. The result of Mathematica shows the method of Lagrange multipliers is applied.

Comment: @user64494. Indeed rounding your solution to x[1]=0.5873, x[2]=0.6771, x[3]=0.4224, x[4]=0.1344, x[5]=0.0133, x[6]=0.0001 and x[>=7]=0, gives $0.451389406$ for any $n\ge 7$.

Comment: It seems likely that the maximum converges as $n\to \infty$ to the maximum to the analogous optimization problem in $\mathbb Z$, i.e. maximize $\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} x_i^2 x_{i+1}$ subject to $\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} x_i^2 =1$. Proving this (maybe with some estimate on the rate of convergence) would be a good solution in my opinion, even if the formulas for any individual $n$ are not so nice.

Comment: @WillSawin It certainly does and incredibly fast, but there is no nice answer for the infinite problem either. What Yaakov pointed out is essentially the maximum: the maximizing sequence decays doubly exponentially, so beyond $x_{12}$ it is invisible to the computer and the trivial iteration like $x_i'\sim x_i+x_{i-1}^2+2x_ix_{i+1}$ converges quickly to the maximizer too. So, for all practical purposes, Yaakov's sequence is optimal (with more precision, of course, which changes only the last digit in his comment to $8$).

Comment: @fedja This all sounds right to me, but can you prove this rigorously? Presumably there is a good way to turn the computer solution for finite $n$ into a rigorous proof for all $n$ but I don't know it. The only thing I have a quick proof of is that $\operatorname{max}_n \leq \max_{\infty} + o(1)$

Comment: @WillSawin Partly yes, but not in full yet. BTW, the quick proof you have gives at most $O(n^{-3/2})$ for the error just because the minimal term is of that order and you can break the chain anywhere. Of course, that is rather short of what I claimed. I'll think more of it and (I hope) post my observations later. Now I'll just note that the Lagrange multiplier theorem gives $\lambda x_i=x_{i-1}^2+2x_ix_{i+1}$ and, since the maximum is $>0.45$, we can multiply by $x_i$, add up, and get $\lambda>1.35$. Since $x_{i+1}$ is less than $0.15$ for most $i$, you get $x_i\le x_{i-1}^2$ most of the time.